# snakemake: MissingOutputException within docker

Tags: docker, snakemake

I am trying to run a pipeline within a docker using snakemake. I am having problem using the `sortmerna` tool to produce `{sample}_merged_sorted_mRNA` and `{sample}_merged_sorted` output from `control_merged.fq` and `treated_merged.fq` input files.

Here my Snakefile:

```
   SAMPLES = ["control","treated"]
   for smp in SAMPLES:
       print("Sample " + smp + " will be processed")
  rule final:
       input:
          expand('/output/{sample}_merged.fq', sample=SAMPLES),
          expand('/output/{sample}_merged_sorted', sample=SAMPLES),
          expand('/output/{sample}_merged_sorted_mRNA', sample=SAMPLES),

  rule sortmerna:
       input: '/output/{sample}_merged.fq',

       output: merged_file='/output/{sample}_merged_sorted_mRNA', merged_sorted='/output/{sample}_merged_sorted',

   message: """---SORTING---"""
   shell:
      '''
         sortmerna --ref /usr/share/sortmerna/rRNA_databases/silva-bac-23s-id98.fasta,/    usr/share/sortmerna/rRNA_databases/index/silva-bac-23s-id98: --reads {input} --paired_in     -a 16 --log --fastx --aligned {output.merged_file} --other {output.merged_sorted} -v
     '''
```

When runnig this I get:

```
Waiting at most 5 seconds for missing files.                                                 
 MissingOutputException in line 57 of /input/Snakefile:                                       
 Missing files after 5 seconds:
/output/control_merged_sorted_mRNA
/output/control_merged_sorted  

 This might be due to filesystem latency. If that is the case, consider to increase the wait $ime with --latency-wait.

 Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
Complete log: /input/.snakemake/log/2018-11-05T091643.911334.snakemake.log
```

I tried to increase the latency with `--latency-wait` but I get the same result. Funny thing is that two output files `control_merged_sorted_mRNA.fq` and `control_merged_sorted.fq` are produced but the program fails and exits. The version of snakemake is 5.3.0. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

snakemake fails because the outputs described by the rule `sortmerna` are not produced. This is not a latency problem, it is a problem with your outputs.

Your rule `sortmerna` expects as output:
`/output/control_merged_sorted_mRNA`
and
`/output/control_merged_sorted`
but the program you are using (I know nothing about sortmerna) is apparently producing
`/output/control_merged_sorted_mRNA.fq`
and
`/output/control_merged_sorted.fq`
Make sure that when you specify the options `--aligned` and `--other` on the command line of your program, it should be the real names of the files produced or if it is only the basename and the program will add a suffix `.fq`. If you are in the latter case, I suggest you use:

```
rule final:
    input:
      expand('/output/{sample}_merged.fq', sample=SAMPLES),
      expand('/output/{sample}_merged_sorted', sample=SAMPLES),
      expand('/output/{sample}_merged_sorted_mRNA', sample=SAMPLES),

rule sortmerna:
   input: 
       '/output/{sample}_merged.fq',
   output: 
       merged_file='/output/{sample}_merged_sorted_mRNA.fq',
       merged_sorted='/output/{sample}_merged_sorted.fq'
   params: 
       merged_file_basename='/output/{sample}_merged_sorted_mRNA',
       merged_sorted_basename='/output/{sample}_merged_sorted'
   message: """---SORTING---"""
   shell:
       """
       sortmerna --ref /usr/share/sortmerna/rRNA_databases/silva-bac-23s-id98.fasta,/usr/share/sortmerna/rRNA_databases/index/silva-bac-23s-id98: --reads {input} --paired_in     -a 16 --log --fastx --aligned {params.merged_file_basename} --other {params.merged_sorted_basename} -v
       """
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured out yesterday and my fix was exactly like yours